# null pointer exception whilst using spring - although bean loaded correctly

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, spring-mvc

i have a bean:

```
public class StatusPollingFilter extends AbstractDiscovery implements UserTester
```

defined as :

```
<bean
id="statusPollingFilter"
class="com.xxxxx.yyyyyyy.zzz.StatusPollingFilter">
<property
    name="evoDao"
    ref="evoDaoFacade">
</property>
```

it loads ok, as logs show:

```
2013-03-07 11:30:14,703 INFO DefaultListableBeanFactory [RunJSPModule] - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@14966cc: defining beans [org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,tilesConfigurer,viewResolver,urlMapping,discovery,statu
sPollingFilter,
```

when i try to use it as:

```
TopoObject topoobj = evoDao.getTopoObjectDao().findById(topoId);
```

evoDao is the main guy doing the work this is defined in:
class AbstractDiscovery
as:

```
//Reference to the DAO facade, for accessing the database via hibernate.
protected EvoTAMDAOFacade evoDao;
```

**The Question?**
because i extend AbstractDiscovery i thought i would be able to access evoDao and use it as normal to get my Dao but it seems not - where am i going wrong?
why can it not find the Dao?

The EvoTAMDAOFacade is injected into AbstractDiscovery as:

```
/**
 * DI method for accessing the DAO facade for accessing the
 * database via hibernate.
 * @param dao 
 */
public void setEvoDao(EvoTAMDAOFacade dao)
{
    this.evoDao = dao;
}
```

the getTopoObjectDao() is defined in the injected EvoTAMDAOFacade of as:

```
public TopoObjectDAO getTopoObjectDao()
{
    return this.topoObjectDao;
}
```

AbstractDiscovery is defined as:

```
public abstract class AbstractDiscovery implements Discovery
```

The exception is :

```
[07 Mar 2013  11:42:24:353] POLL: Exception while getting obj during status update java.lang.NullPointerException 162.109.37.114 at:
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**Another Q?** the statusPollFilter is running as thread in a scheduler for multiple objects  - i'm not actually sure i should be defining it as a singleton bean but how do i access the Dao if i don't?

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is `TopoObjectDAO` also injected into `EvoTAMDAOFacade`?  That being null could also cause your problem.

Comment: it is injected but that's what i expect - obviously i'm making some schoolboy type error here, but i cant see it.  I expect the injected  TopoObjectDAO to be instantiated via spring and initially be null but be populated via the .findById(topoId); method.  or i'm i mising some pt here.  i thought the fact that it is a DAO and hooked to hibernate via its TopoObject.hbm.xml this would all be handled via hibernate and i would get a populated object back or do i need to create it from the id first somehow??  thanks for your help.

Comment: have you tried setting break points in the set methods, making sure they are called when the applicaiton loads?

Comment: yes, i've done that and both setters for EvoTAMDAOFacade and TopoObjectDAO are called when application loads.  strange thing is the same code with same DI objects gets called exactly same way elsewhere and works fine.  which is why i'm asking the second question, namely, the poller is run via a scheduler thread and implements a 3rd party api interface and i'm not sure if i should be creating a singleton spring bean of it for purposes of DI. Nevertheless it does get created and spring doesn't complain about the poller bean, i inject the EvoTAMDAOFacade into poller bean expecting acces 2 my DAO

Comment: actually when i do this in StatusPollingFilter '  private EvoTAMDAOFacade evoDao; public void setEvoDao(EvoTAMDAOFacade dao)
 {
  this.evoDao = dao;
 }' in  it doesnt inject the dao.  i debug it shows doesn't get loaded. but the spring bean StatusPollingFilter is created.

Comment: from AbstractDiscovery in debug it shows the setter is called for evoDao within AbstractDiscovery. but if i access from StatusPollingFilter having extended AbstractDiscovery it still comes up null in StatusPollingFilter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

having read more - i have come across the ans.
because the StatusPollingFilter object is under control of scheduler (i knew that scheduler had something to do with it) then it is unaware of the spring beans which is why i keep getting null when i try injecting the bean.

i created a class:

```
 ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware
```

added static access

```
private static ApplicationContext   appContext;
```

did a setter for it :

```
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context)
{
    appContext = context;
}
```

and added

```
public static Object getBean(String beanName) throws BeansException
{
    return appContext.getBean(beanName);
}
```

used in code as :

```
EvoTAMDAOFacade evoDao = (EvoTAMDAOFacade) ApplicationContextProvider.getBean("evoDaoFacade");
```

i now have access to the facade bean and all injected beans into facade.
i still have an issue with hibernate session but thats prob due to some other issue.

pt here is i don't have access to the bean as its not in control of the spring container so i needed to somehow get it , probably could have done it via the factory method but why mess around when there a simpler way.
thanks for help by anyone who may have posted or tried to understand my problem.